# Delphi-7 (150), and LocalSQL - the old BDE 32-Bit from BORLAND - INSERT INTO ErrorMessage

Tags: join

Okay, I know, that the BORLAND BDE-32Bit is a little bit Retro, but I would like using it, because I would like no install a complete Server Solution on my small Desktop PC.

Okay. Starting with this Error-Message:

```
INSERT INTO "E:\table.dbf" (NAME,SIZE,WEIGHT,AREA,BMP) VALUES ("foo","42","21,"007","");
```

The Error Message after ExecSQL statement is:
Invalid use of keyword.
Token: SIZE,WEIGHT,AREA,BMP)
Line Number: 1.

I can not find any mistakes, or is the INSERT INTO command no supported in LocalSQL ?

Comment: I would advise against using such a dated technology, and if you're looking for a local database system, then something like SQLite would be a good choice.

Comment: @J.D. Thank you for the information. But I have to deal with some (old) Technoliegis Databases - I write on a Retro-Project. But this should not the Problem (in my Opinion). It seems the SQL command are wrong? And I am thinking, that SQL is Platform independed, and comes with a Basic ISO Standard. Either the Field Names are reserved, or it is an other Problem. I am not sure.

Comment: Yes there's a standard for SQL, but each database system has their own variation with syntax and features. It's usually best to use one that's modern because of the availability of documentation & communities of people using it. I'm not familiar with Borland other than knowing it's quite old and hardly used, relatively speaking. But if the syntax is the same as other modern database systems, then the problem is like this `"E:\table.dbf"`. It looks like you're trying to insert directly into the database file but instead you should be inserting into a specific Table that belongs to the database.

Comment: I've no idea if LocalSQL follows the SQL standard, but in standard SQL character literals are enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: hello @mustaccio, I think, I have found out, that the JediVCL Components don't support LocalSQL. Because I have not directly access to dBASE based database files. The main stream seems to be to tend to ADO Databases like dbExpress, MSSQL, Interbase, ... . I found a work around, to access the Table data directly. So I can insert/append/delete in native mode. But this is a little bit slower as collect INSERT INTO and do a COMMIT at end of all, instead handling insert data directly (and not directly with SQL commands). But I et all, I solve it. Thank You for all Attention's, Jens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to give a Solution for my Problem as WorkAround that based upon the Topic Header Posting from me from 23.10.2002 for Delphi-7 (150) 32-Bit:

1. I created a new TApplication, and a new TForm,
2. On the TForm1, I put a TDBGrid, a TDataSource, and a TTable Component,
3. I give the TTable Component a Database(Name), and a Table(Name),
4. I give the TDataSource the Information about the TTable,
5. I give the TDBGrid the TDataSource Component on the TForm.

All other Commands should be trival:

```
with Table1 do
begin
  Open;
  Edit;
  FieldByName('FIELD_NAME').AsString := 'foo';
  Post;
end;
```

The example in the Code section above show the "directly way".
Dont forget, that I had created the Table1 with its fields.
This Methode can be used with Delphi-7 till Currently Berlin/Merlyn Versions - or the corresponding C++ Builder Versions beginning at C++ Builder 6.0, and upwards.